# Are there system collection types that handle loop-over automatically when mapping different size collections to each other?

Tags: c#

I have a collection of columns and an int collection of widths I want to apply to them. How do I make them independent of the size of each other?

Say I have columns `[col1, col2, col3, col4, col5]` and widths `[10,15,20]` the result should be

```
col1: 10
col2: 15
col3: 20
col4: 10
col5: 15
```

And for `[col1, col2]` and `[10,15,20]`

```
col1: 10
col2: 15
```

I did similar things manually before by manipulating indices in custom type lists like `if (i == widths.Length()) {i=0}`, but is there anything in system types or methods that handle cyclic loop-overs automatically?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: OP's intention seems to be _creating_ that relation that up until then did not exist.

Comment: The closest thing to this in the framework is [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip), but it does not cycle. (Of course, in general, it couldn't, as you void the warranty of many enumerables by trying to enumerate them more than once.)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's no existing thing that does this. However, it's not that hard to develop yourself. Are you open to custom implementations?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://dotnetfiddle.net/0vlb2S

Comment: Sounds like the modulus operator might be useful...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I'm not understanding your question. OP is trying to _create_ that combined list that you say he should have; but he doesn't know how to do so. OP wants to assign a cyclical value (numbers) to a given list (columns). This is in essence no different from e.g. distributing a list of people over a given list of teams (assigning one person to a team cyclically, in order to balance the teams as best as possible).

Comment: @KhanhTO I'm actually applying that width to a column in an autotest, but mostly yes, and I did such a thing before, I was wondering if something supports it outside of the box. The more I think the more it seems that nuance of implementation can vary a lot and that's the reason it is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modus

```
public static void CombineList()
{
    List<string> cols = new List<string> {"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7"};
    List<string> nums = new List<string> { "10", "20", "50"};
    int numsCount = nums.Count;
    List<string> comb = new List<string>();
    for(int i = 0; i < cols.Count; i++)
    {
        string s = $"{cols[i]}: {nums[i%numsCount]}";
        Debug.WriteLine(s);
        comb.Add(s);    
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("done");
}

col1: 10
col2: 20
col3: 50
col4: 10
col5: 20
col6: 50
col7: 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If your collections are indexed (say using ArrayList), then you can just use modulo arithmetic on the column and weight collections. The weight to assign would be something like

columnWeight = weight[ columnIndex % # of weights]

Comment: Will probably end up with something like that

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like this that takes a collection as an input and returns it so that its values are repeated until the minimum length is reached.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> RepeatToMinimumLength<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, 
    int minimumLength)
{
    var inputAsList = input as List<T> ?? input.ToList();
    if (inputAsList.Count >= minimumLength) 
        return inputAsList.Take(minimumLength);
    if (!inputAsList.Any()) 
        throw new ArgumentException("input must have at least one element.");
    var output = new List<T>(inputAsList);

    while(output.Count < minimumLength)
        output.AddRange(inputAsList);
    return output.Take(minimumLength);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list extension to handle it nicely. Call it an `Expand` method or whatever. Note it'll modify your original data, so modulo `%` approach or creating method returning new collection is overall safer.

```
public static class SomeListExtensions
{
    public static void Expand<T>( this List<T> list, int count )
    {
        if ( count < list.Count )
        {
            list.RemoveRange( count, list.Count - count );
        }
        else if ( count > list.Count )
        {
            int oldCount = list.Count;
            for ( int i = oldCount; i < count; i++ )
                list.Add( list[ i % oldCount ] );
        }
    }
}
```

Following code returns `10, 15, 20, 10, 15`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        List<int> values = new List<int>();
        values.Add( 10 );
        values.Add( 15 );
        values.Add( 20 );

        List<string> groups = new List<string>();
        groups.Add( "col1" );
        groups.Add( "col2" );
        groups.Add( "col3" );
        groups.Add( "col4" );
        groups.Add( "col5" );

        values.Expand( groups.Count );
        Console.WriteLine( string.Join( ", ", values ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a specialized implementation of `Enumerable.Zip`:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ZipCycle<TSource1, TSource2, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource1> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource2> second,
    Func<TSource1, TSource2, TResult> selector)
{
    if (first == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(first));

    if (second == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(second));

    if (selector == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(selector));

    return InnerZip();

    IEnumerable<TResult> InnerZip()
    {
        using (var f = first.GetEnumerator())
        using (var s = second.GetEnumerator())
        {
            var firstIteration = true;

            while (f.MoveNext())
            {
                if (!s.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (firstIteration)
                    {
                        yield break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        s.Reset();
                        s.MoveNext();
                    }
                }

                yield return selector(f.Current, s.Current);
                firstIteration = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should do the trick.